# Prove that any $x$ in $\{0,1,\dots,N-1\}$ can be uniquely expressed in the form $i+jn$, where $n=1+\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ and let $n=1+\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$.
Then each $x\in\{0,1,\dots,N-1\}$ can be expressed uniquely in the form $i+jn$ for some $i,j\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.

How would I go about proving this? My first instinct was to show that one could find an $i$ and a $j$ such that $i+nj=1$, and then take multiples of that to generate the rest of the set, but that won't work since $i$ and $j$ are bounded in $[0,n-1]$.

Comment: Think: two base-$b$ digits give you $b^2$ options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remark:* We need $N\ge 0$ for this to work; in fact otherwise we have problems defining $n$. But for $N\ge0$ we at least have $n\ge 1$.

There are two things to be shown: existence and uniqueness.

Let's start with uniqueness: Suppose we have $i,j,i',j'\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ with $i+jn=i'+j'n$. Then $i-i'=(j'-j)n$. So $i-i'$ is a multiple of $n$, but on the other hand is between $-(n-1)$ and $n-1)$, inclusive. This is only possible if $i-i'=0$, and as $n\ne0$ so also $j-j'=0$.

Once we have uniqueness, existence is easy. There are $n$ choices for $i$ and $n$ choices for $j$ when producing $i+nj$. By uniqueness, we thus can represent $n^2$ different numbers. On the other hand, $i+nj\ge 0+n\cdot 0=0$ and $i+nj\le (n-1)+n(n-1)=n^2-1$, so all these $n^2$ representable numbers must be among the $n^2$ numbers $\{0,\ldots,n^2-1\}$. In other words: Each integer $\in\{0,\ldots, n^2-1\}$ is representable. Hence it suffics to show that $0\le N\le n^2$. But from $\sqrt N-1< \lfloor \sqrt N\rfloor\le\sqrt N$, we see that $n>\sqrt N$ and so $n^2>N$.

*Remark:* Consequently, we could also allow $x\in\{0,1,\ldots, N\}$.